# Laravel - route("resource.destroy") calls "resource.show"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, crud

This is the `web.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],
    function () {
        Route::get('letters/getRows', 'LetterController@getRows')->name('letters.getRows');
        Route::get('letters/{letter}/A4', 'LetterController@A4')->name('letters.A4');
        Route::get('letters/{letter}/A5', 'LetterController@A5')->name('letters.A5');
        Route::resource('letters', 'LetterController');
    }
);
```

I created a link as follow

```
"<a class='mx-2 h5' href='".route('letters.destroy', $entity->id)."'><i class='icon-remove-circle'></i></a>".
```

where the `$entity->id` is the `id` of the letter. The problem is, it links to `show` method not the `destroy` method. What can I do?

Using a form like this

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('letters.destroy', $entity->id), 'method' => 'delete')) }}
    <button type="submit" >Delete Account</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

may solve the problem but I want to use `a` tag not a form.

## update

In the `php artisan route:list`, the url of destroy and show are the same

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `Route::resource` method it will create, among others, a route to DESTROY a resource like this: `/letters/:id/` and another route to EDIT the resource: `/letters/:id`, and one more to SHOW `/letters/:id`

They all look the same. However, the difference is in the HTTP method/verb used to reach each route.

If you look to the output if `php artisan route:list`, you will find the list of HTTP methods used. Something like:

```
GET|HEAD  | letters/{letter} | letters.show 
PUT|PATCH | letters/{letter} | letters.update
DELETE    | letters/{letter} | letters.destroy
```

Therefore, to show a letter, you use a `GET` method, to edit a letter, use `PUT` method, and to destroy/delete, you use a `DELETE` method.

When you use an `a` tag, the browser will use the `GET` method, thus will reach the `letters.show` route. Html forms, can use `POST` or `GET`. Finally to use the `DELETE` http method, you need a form with hidden input named `_method` and the `value="delete` inside the form. Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing) for more details.

There is also a note about this in [LaravelCollective package documentations](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html)

> Note: Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field to your form.

**Finally,** if you must use an anchor tag `<a>`, you could use javascript to listen to the click event and submit a form with `DELETE` method.

**Update to add an example**:
You can find an example of using an anchor tag to submit the form, in the default app layout in the framework [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/be92f84136374919d5d506ee1c1126ca80e6e63d/src/Illuminate/Auth/Console/stubs/make/views/layouts/app.stub#L57-L65)

And this is a modified version to submit a delete request:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                     document.getElementById('destroy-form').submit();">
    {{ __('DELETE') }}
</a>

<form id="destroy-form" action="{{ route('letters.destroy', $entity) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant. If you want to make a `DELETE` request you need to spoof it via a form (method `POST`, `_method` `DELETE`) or use Javascript.

Hyperlinks will cause new requests which will be `GET` requests. That is just how the web works.